# Run docker container from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins

I currently run a Jenkins instance inside a Docker container. I've been doing some experimenting with Jenkins and their pipelines. I managed to make my Maven app build successful using a Jenkinsfile.

Right now I am trying to automatically deploy the app I built to a docker container that's a sibling to the Jenkins container. I did already mount the /var/run/docker.sock so I have access to the parent docker. But right now I can't seem to find any good information to guide me through the next part, which is modifying the Jenkinsfile to deploy my app in a new container.

How would I go over and run my Maven app inside a sibling docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be more appropriate to spin up a slave node (a physical or virtual box) and then run something in there with docker.

If you check your instance URL: https://jenkins.address/job/myjob/pipeline-syntax/

You will find more information about what are the commands you need for this.

Anyway best way to do this is to actually create a dockerfile and as a step copy the artifact in it, push the image to a registry and then find somewhere to deploy the just built image